# Apache error AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of 000-default.conf, URL to redirect is missing

Tags: ssl, apache2, digital-ocean, http-redirect

I'm using a droplet at Digital Ocean with a server running Ubuntu 20.04,(Apache/2.42.49, MySQL, PHP7.2.24 setup) and a droplet running opensource social network (ossn 5.2) for the non-profit group I'm setting this up for. The domain is pointed to the DigitalOcean name servers (ns1.digitalocean.com.,ns2.digitalocean.com.,ns3.digitalocean.com.) and the A record points to the Ipv4 address of the Droplet. Everything was working at http after installation and configuration. I received the SSL certificates from ZeroSSL and I have edited the 000-default.conf to use the SSL certificates (I am using the naming scheme and directory outlined by Digital Ocean [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority] in their instructions) with the code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ihn.my-domain.org
    Redirect permanent https://ihn.my-domain.org
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    
    ServerName ihn.my-domain.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@my-domain.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/sammy/ihn.my-domain.org.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/sammy/ihn.my-domain.org.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/sammy/intermediate.crt

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The error I keep getting when running apachectl configtest is:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: 
URL to direct to is missing. 
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error and I can't find any different example, here or elsewhere, online of how a simple http to https redirect should be constructed other than what I have within the instructions on the Digital Ocean help site. Am I missing brackets or quotation marks? DigitalOcean's instructions are for Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache, and I don't know if there is something I'm missing that has been changed for Ubuntu 20.04. The help information from ZeroSSL (https://help.zerossl.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015629239-Installing-SSL-Certificate-on-Apache) shows what to write in the <Virtualhost *:443> section of the configuration file, but nothing on setting a permanent redirect from port 80 to port 443. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... I have to have a FROM TO statement on the redirect. So...

```
Redirect permanent http://ihn.my-domain.org https://ihn.my-domain.org
```

the configtest was only finding one URL and it was assuming it was the FROM and there wasn't a TO to direct toward.